# Are exploding axles common?

Tags: subaru, axle, forester, cv-joint

I just got my '99 Subaru Foresters front CV axles both replaced two weeks ago, but just this last Friday while I was driving home one of the new axles "exploded". I'm wondering if that's something that'll happen every once in a blue moon with new axles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, exploding axles are not a normal thing. Return to the shop that replaced them, there should be a warranty on them. Either:

- the axles were defective
- the axles weren't installed properly
- the axles were the incorrect ones for your vehicle

Comment: Yeah, the shop replaced them I was just curious how often something like that happens.

Comment: I've seen an improperly installed axle do that before.  One the test drive.  About a quarter mile from the shop.  POP!  Strange noises.  Bearings rolling away, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing that it must have been a factory defect because I got like 800 miles on it before it snapped. Just a bit farther than that quarter mile.

Comment: Where did it snap off at exactly? Did it just pull out the transmission like the C clip failed? Or did it snap down the center like this example [Honda Civic - CV Axle Snapped In Half](https://youtu.be/qy43rntdb8s?t=184)